# Pandas: Is there any way to add specific columns in dataframe based on conditional match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have columns from Jan to Dec and depending on the current month, i have to get sum of months. For example: If current month is April, my code should add all columns from Jan to April and ignore all others.

Original Table:

```
| Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec |   |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|---|
| 2   | 3   | 4   | 5   | 6   | 7   | 8   | 9   | 12  | 1   | 3   | 5   |   |
| 1   | 23  | 4   | 5   | 76  | 7   | 423 | 57  | 689 | 345 | 23  | 2   |   |
```

I have huge data set with multiple columns for past 3 years, lets say 2015, 2016, 2017. Each year i have columns like:
Jan','Feb','Mar' and so on.

I need to get summations of each column for each year separately. So i made list and then i added them up. But this approach is too lengthy.

I also tried to set values in other columns (in this example May-Dec) to zero so that only Jan-April will be added. This approach also works but it involves a lot of code and too much room for manual errors in case any new modification is required in future.

```py
list_2015 = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']

df1['2015_Dec_YTD'] = df1.loc[:,list_2015].sum(axis=1)
```

If i create this way, it works properly but then the code gets too lengthy since for each month, i have to create a separate list which will allow m the addition of those columns.

I am looking for a easier way for conditional add of columns in dataframe to create a new column. Basic workflow will be :
if current_month = April, then (sum till current month) = (Jan+Feb+Mar+April)

Expected output:

```
| Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec |  SUM till current month |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-------------------------|
| 2   | 3   | 4   | 5   | 6   | 7   | 8   | 9   | 12  | 1   | 3   | 5   | 14                      |
| 1   | 23  | 4   | 5   | 76  | 7   | 423 | 57  | 689 | 345 | 23  | 2   | 33                      |
```

Answer (score 1):

Perform a [`Boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) by columns based on `current_month`:

```
current_month='Apr'
current_mask=pd.Series(df.columns.str.contains(current_month)).shift(fill_value=False).cumsum().eq(0)
print(current_mask)
```

---

```
0      True
1      True
2      True
3      True
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11    False
dtype: bool
```

---

```
df['SUM till current month']=df[df.columns[current_mask]].sum(axis=1)
print(df)
```

---

```
   Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec  \
0    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   12    1    3    5   
1    1   23    4    5   76    7  423   57  689  345   23    2   

   SUM till current month  
0                      14  
1                      33
```

---

**Details:**

[`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) 
 is used to locate the month until which we want to obtain the sum.
So the goal is to get a mask with True in this column and the previous ones

```
current_month='Apr'
df.columns.str.contains(current_month)

array([False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False])
```

---

For this we use [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) + [`Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to differentiate these columns:

```
pd.Series(df.columns.str.contains(current_month)).shift(fill_value=False)
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4      True
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11    False
dtype: bool
```

---

```
pd.Series(df.columns.str.contains(current_month)).shift(fill_value=False).cumsum()

0     0
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     1
8     1
9     1
10    1
11    1
dtype: int64
```

---

Now we create the mask by selecting them with [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html)

```
pd.Series(df.columns.str.contains(current_month)).shift(fill_value=False).cumsum().eq(0)


0      True
1      True
2      True
3      True
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks, but the month variable will change every 30 days. I am trying to get a code which will be robust enough to work whenever the variable 'month' changes, it should be able to give updated output, without any changes on the code.

Comment: I have updated the solution so that it is a function of `current_month`.Check now

Comment: That works perfect. Thanks a lot. Appreciate your efforts. Could you please provide any specific details how this works exactly?

current_mask=pd.Series(df.columns.str.contains(current_month)).shift(fill_value=False).cumsum().eq(0)

Comment: Glad to help, I have added the details of how the Series for Boolean indexing is obtained step by step.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something like "if current_month = April...", you can use `get_loc` with `iloc`:

```
df.iloc[:,:df.columns.get_loc("Apr")+1].sum(axis=1)

#
0    14
1    33
dtype: int64
```